# innerHTML isn't changing onClick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, innerhtml

I want to use my button to add a line of text underneath whatever is already existing in the `textarea` field. Sometimes it is populated, other times it is not (determined by the `$Item["description"]`).

It works when I try it in a W3schools editor, so what am I missing? Is it something to do with the placement of a div inside the text area?

```js
function addNewMessage() {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<p><em>Here is the new message!</em></p>";
}
```

```html
<textarea name='short_description' id='short_desc' form='edit_item'>
  <div id='container'>Foo bar</div>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use W3Schools. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. There are far better resources, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference), and better scratchpad tools, just as [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and [Codepen](https://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place other elements inside a `<textarea>`. Use a `contenteditable` div element instead.

```js
function addNewMessage() {
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<p><em>Here is the new message!</em></p>";
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" contenteditable></div>

<input type='button' class='inputbutton' value='Add New Message' onclick="addNewMessage()">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your HTML is invalid, and the way you're trying to update it in the JS is incorrect. The `textarea` element can only contain text, not rendered HTML, so placing the `<div id="container" />` element there will not work.

To do what you require, change the HTML so that the `textarea` only contains text, then update your JS to retrieve the `#short_desc` element and update its `value` instead of its `innerHTML`:

```js
function addNewMessage() {
  document.getElementById("short_desc").value += "Here is the new message! ";
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="short_description" id="short_desc" form="edit_item">Foo bar </textarea>

<input type="button" class="inputbutton" value="Add New Message" onclick="addNewMessage()" />
```